# Why does GO compiler add a pointer value receiver method to the method set of non-pointer type when using the pointer Type Embedding?

Tags: go

First of all, I want to say that my question is not based on a specific problem, but is based on a potential discussion of why the GO compiler behaves in a certain way. I expect that potential experts in the given language (or at least people with serious experience) could explain this potentially strange behavior.

Also, the title might be a little confusing because I'm not sure how to explain in one sentence (one question) without an example and a more detailed story.

To clearly explain what the question in the title means, let me start from a situation that behaves as I expect.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyType1 struct {
    MyType2
}

type MyType2 struct {
}

func (MyType2) Function1() {
}

func (*MyType2) Function2() {
}

func main() {
    t1 := reflect.TypeOf(MyType1{})
    t2 := reflect.TypeOf(&MyType1{})

    fmt.Println(t1, "has", t1.NumMethod(), "methods:")
    for i := 0; i < t1.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Print(" method#", i, ": ", t1.Method(i).Name, "\n")
    }

    fmt.Println(t2, "has", t2.NumMethod(), "methods:")
    for i := 0; i < t2.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Print(" method#", i, ": ", t2.Method(i).Name, "\n")
    }
}
```

When the type embedding is based on "type" (not correct name, but let's call it like that) everything behaves as I expect. The structure `MyType1` has a `MyType2` embedded field ("type" embedded field) so the type `MyType1` will have the method `(MyType1)Function1()` in its method set and the type `*MyType1` will have the methods `(*MyType1)Function1()` and `(*MyType1)Function2()` in its method set. So, each type (`MyType1` and `*MyType1`) will get their corresponding methods. `*MyType1` will get the method `(*MyType1)Function1()` because it's implicitly arises from `(MyType1)Function1()`. So, as I said before, everything is expected. To prove this, I also used the standard "reflect" package and got the following printout:

```
main.MyType1 has 1 methods:
 method#0: Function1
*main.MyType1 has 2 methods:
 method#0: Function1
 method#1: Function2
```

A strange behavior occurs when I replace the "type" embedded field with a "pointer type" embedded field (`MyType1` now has `*MyType2` instead of `MyType2`). So the code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyType1 struct {
    *MyType2
}

type MyType2 struct {
}

func (MyType2) Function1() {
}

func (*MyType2) Function2() {
}

func main() {
    t1 := reflect.TypeOf(MyType1{})
    t2 := reflect.TypeOf(&MyType1{})

    fmt.Println(t1, "has", t1.NumMethod(), "methods:")
    for i := 0; i < t1.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Print(" method#", i, ": ", t1.Method(i).Name, "\n")
    }

    fmt.Println(t2, "has", t2.NumMethod(), "methods:")
    for i := 0; i < t2.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Print(" method#", i, ": ", t2.Method(i).Name, "\n")
    }

}
```

Now what is actually the crux of the problem. The prints is:

```
main.MyType1 has 2 methods:
 method#0: Function1
 method#1: Function2
*main.MyType1 has 2 methods:
 method#0: Function1
 method#1: Function2
```

So, somehow `MyType1` also has method `(MyType1)Function2()` even though it is not declared as **value receiver method** for type `MyType2`.

Does anyone have any logical explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: That’s what the language spec mandates.

Comment: They "Why?" of such question about language design is opinion based in 95% of all cases (5% are "you would have to solve the halting problem to do otherwise" or that like) and thus unfit for _SO_. Just ask such stuff on the golang-nuts mailing list which is the perfect place to get an answer from the language designers themself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple explanation is: If type A embeds type B, type A gets all methods of type B.

In your first example, `MyType2` is embedded into `MyType1`, and `MyType2` has one function, `Function1`, so `MyType1` also gets `Function1`.

In your second example, `*MyType2` has two functions, `Function1` and `Function2`, so `MyType1` has both of those functions.

The important point here is that methods defined with a pointer receiver of type `A` are only defined for `*A`, and not for `A`. The reason for that is to provide proper semantics for interfaces.

Let's say you have an interface:

```
type MyIntf interface {
   Function2()
}
```

If there is a function:

```
func f(m MyIntf) {
   m.Function2()
}
```

then this property prevents you from passing `MyType1` to `f`, because if it were allowed, the modifications `f` made on that object by calling `Function2` would be lost. You can only pass `MyType2`, or the second `MyType1` implementation, in which case any modifications made on `m` will be reflected on the passed instance of the value.

Comment: "In your first example, MyType2 is embedded into MyType1, and MyType2 has one function, Function2, so MyType1 also gets Function2." What? In my first example (more correct, in both examples), MyType2 has one method and it's Function1, not Function2 as you said. MyType1 does not get Function2 but Function1. I print it with "reflect" standard package to prove it.

Comment: 1/3 So, if I understood it correctly. If embedded field is "type embedded field" (in example 1 it's MyType2) then type that has embedded field (in example MyType1) will get all value receiver methods correspond to embedded field (in example MyType2 has (MyType2)Function1, so MyType1 will also have it - (MyType1)Function1). On the other hand, *MyType1 will get all pointer receiver methods from embedded field (in example, pointer receiver methods of MyType2 are (*MyType2)Function1 and (*MyType2)Function2, so *MyType1 will also have it - (*MyType1)Function1 and (*MyType1)Function2).

Comment: 2/3 If embedded field is "pointer type embedded field" (in example 2 it's *MyType2) then type that has embedded field (in example MyType1) will get all pointer receiver methods correspond to embedded field (in example *MyType2 has (*MyType2)Function1 and (*MyType2)Function2, so MyType1 will also have it - (MyType1)Function1 and (MyType1)Function2). No matter Function2 is pointer receiver method in MyType2, MyType1 (no pointer type) will have it as value receiver method? (WHAT, WHAT and WHAT?)

Comment: 3/3 On the other hand, *MyType1 will get (*MyType1)Function1 and (*MyType1)Function2, so it's expected for me. Did I understand it good? Can you tell me how will methods (MyType)Function1 and (MyType)Function2 behave when they arose from pointer receiver methods (especially Function2)? I mean, their implementation is for pointers not for values.

Comment: That is difficult to follow, but I think correct. To rephrase, if A embeds B, type A has all value receiver methods of B, and type *A has all value+pointer receivers of B. If A embed *B, A has all value and pointer methods of B.

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I write. I have only one more question. It's related to "If A embed *B, A has all value and pointer methods of B.". How will A implements these methods as value receiver methods when they are created for pointers (their implementation, function body, is for pointers and addresses)?

Comment: The implementation for those methods will be for *B, not A. Those methods will always get a *B.

Comment: So implementation will be for *B, but A will have the methods? Does it mean that "receiver parameter" in method is of type *B or of type A. I mean, will it be:
func (b *B) Function2(){} or 
func (a A) Function2(){} ?
If the second one is correct (I mean, it's more logical for me since it is now method of A), will it implicitly then, before function body starts, take the "&b" from "a" and then use it inside function body "func (a A) Function2()"? I hope it is clear what I want to ask.

Comment: `Function2` is implemented for `*B`. When you call `a.Function2()` where `a` is of type `A`, the `Function2` will be called on `a.B`. In other words, `a.Function2()` and `a.B.Function2()` are equivalent.

Comment: So it will "stay" in form of (*B)Function2 but will also be in method set of type A? Okay, but for each method, a corresponding function is created. So, for method (*B)Function2() in method set of A, compiler should create a function (A).Function2(b *B), but it instead creates the function (A)Function2(a A). How is that possible if implementation stays for *B?

Comment: No, compiler does not generate a function. The function name appears in the method set of A, that's it. There is only one implementation of Function2, and it is for *B.

Comment: Okay, let's say compiler does not generate the function, but the function name appears in method set of A, then why does that function takes (a A) as a receiver parameter and not (b *B)? I mean, implementation is for *B, why does it take A as a parameter?

Comment: Well, I can't agree with you that compiler does not implement function for method. Let's say we have: "type MyType struct{}" and method for that type "func (MyType) Function1(){}". When you do the following:   b := MyType2{};   fmt.Printf("%p\n", MyType2.Function1);   fmt.Printf("%p\n", b.Function1). These two prints give two different addresses. So, it means that compiler does create the implicit function, right?

Comment: That does not print the address of the function. That prints the address of the closure that captures the receiver. The function called is the same, and it is `MyType2.Function2`

Comment: Well, when I add one more variable: c := MyType2{} and print fmt.Printf("%p\n", c.Function1). It gives same result as fmt.Printf("%p\n", b.Function1). If it prints the address of the closure that captures the receiver how is this possible?

Comment: This might help: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values